# Span text color change onclick, back to original on release?

Tags: html

I can't find a specific code application for just changing text color within a span tag while button is pressed then changes back on release.

I've seen references that an onclick event can be combined with a span without any css styling but not found any working models that I could apply to this.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I'll take a an answer that requires css styling, just wanted to keep it simple if possible.

Update: You can down vote all you like, I don't come in here asking ?'s if I haven't already spent hours looking, I don't like to ask for help if I can figure it out on my own & I don't look to see if someone has already tried to solve their problem. If I can help, I do so thx for the answer but that kind of comment is an annoying assumption.

These answers didn't help tho. I'm using a chatbox written in js & modifying it's appearance to my taste the following is the section of code for the button I'm try to modify. It doesn't validate but looks & functions fine on my site except that I can't figure out how to change the button text color on click.

```
 <table width="279px" border="0" cellpadding="5" align="center">
 <tr>
 <th onclick="window.location="cursor:pointer;onMouseover="this.bgColor='#606060';" onMouseout="this.bgColor='';"><span style="outline: 1px solid #000000;display:inline-block;padding-bottom:1px;border:2px solid #888888;box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 1px #454545;background:#000000">
 <button onclick="set_cookie(); return clearMessageBox();" style="font-size:14px; font-family:arial; color:#1DBD01; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid black; background-color:#000000; height:33px">Click or hit enter to send message</button></span></th>
```

Comment: I believe you are getting downvoted for this, because you haven't shown any attempt at getting this to work.  In general it's better to post your research or what you've tried yourself.  

This will go a long way in getting people to help you out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but will require CSS. I don't have a CSS-free solution for you, unfortunately.

jQuery:

```
$( "#target" ).mousedown(function() {
  $( ".myspan" ).toggleClass( "changeColor" );
});
$( "#target" ).mouseup(function() {
  $( ".myspan" ).toggleClass( "changeColor" );
});
```

html

```
<button id="target">Click me</button>
<span class="myspan">I am some really awesome text!</span>
```

css

```
span {font-size:3em;}
.changeColor {color:red;}
```

and link to demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/o73jk7es/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in pure css

```css
button:active ~span{color:red;font-size:150%;}
#secondButton:active {color:lime;font-weight:bold;box-shadow:2px 2px 2px lime;}
```

```html
<button>The Button</button>
<span> The text</span>
<button id="secondButton"><span>2nd Button</span></button>
<button onmousedown="this.style.color='red'" onmouseup="this.style='inherit'"><span>Inline Style</span></button>
```

Comment: Thx Billy, that code works great for a regular button but didn't with my modified button so I'm still scratchin' my head on this

Comment: Can you give your button an ID, I see from the code above you have the styles inline, is it normally like that on your site or was that for illustration purposes

Comment: just read the update, So it's the color of the text on the button you want to change , I'll add a second button to my answer with inline styles that you can add to the page, it would be better to add the styles in a stylesheet though

Comment: couldn't do the css active class inline so had to usse JS, one of the 3 buttons should help you. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

I  figured out the answer to my ? & thx to Billy's lead that gave me the idea.

This code will give the button text a different color on click...

```
 css= button:active { color:#your color } but if you have several buttons & want to target a particular 1 then you do button:active span.one { color:#your color } & your button code looks like this....<button><span class="one">text</span></button>
```

So case closed on this. cheers all